# Cook's distance plot from vector in R

Tags: r, plot

I am tyring to dectect outlier with cook's distance in R.

Im using the r-package "betareg"(for beta regression). So, its quite difficult to use the normal cooks.distance plot.

But with the r command: cooks.distance(model) I get as an answer an vector with cooks distances for each observations.

`mod1<- betareg(y~ a+b+c+d|a+b+c+d, data=d) cooks.distance(mod1)  #returns a vector`

But I don't know how to turn this vector into a plot like this below (with observation numbers):

Thanks for help!

[image: Cook´s Distance plot]

Comment: try plot(cooks.distance(mod1), type = "h")

Comment: Thanks, I can see the plot now. What is still missing, are the numbers of observations above the "distance lines". I just cannot figure out how to make them appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <- cooks.distance(mod1)
plot(1:length(cd), cd, type = "h", ylim = range(cd)*c(1, 1.1))# stretch y-axis to make space for labels
threshold <- 0.25 # choose appropriate value
lab <- cd > thresh
myLabels <- 1:length(cd) # choose appropriate labels
text(which(lab), cd[lab], labels = myLabels[lab], pos = 3)# pos 3 puts labels above position
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again.One problem: `text(which(lab), cd[lab], labels = myLabels[lab], pos = 3)` R answers with `Error in which(lab) : argument to 'which' is not logical` And: Is here an mistake? `lab <- cd > thresh`